# The core difference between phonetics and phonology

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary, questions, phrase-requests, idiom-meaning

What are the differences between phonetics and phonology?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. What have you discovered in your research? Your question might be better at https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about phonetics, not English. [linguistics.se] would be a better fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phoneticians are mostly interested in the articulation and physical nature of the sounds of a language, while phonologists try to construct entire sound systems for languages, including their acquisition and development over time.  Often, linguists have interests in both areas.